# not able to access JDK path in intelliJ in Jetstream XSEDE cloud

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ubuntu-18.04

I am having issue when trying to associate my intelliJ project with JDK in JetStream Xsede cloud. Whey trying to access the directory through intelliJ, I can see a locked folder icon which don't allows to access it.

Steps that I followed to set the JDK in intelliJ:

1. Open project structure (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>s</kbd>)
2. Go to Project Setting->project
3. Click on the new Button under Project SDK

Please let me know if any further information are required to recreate the issue.

Comment: Where this JDK directory is located? You can set the locally installed JDK in IDE.

Comment: @Andrey the JDK is located in this location: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by performing
`chmod 777 /usr/lib/jvm` in the terminal.
Once I run this command, the lock design disappears, and the directory becomes accessible.

[image: The lock design in the directory]

Thanks.
Prashant